# Decompose polynomial into irreducible polynomials over Q[x] using complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

> I need to decompose polynomial $x^{14}+1$ into irreducibles over $\mathbb Q[x]$.

It is assumed that I will use complex numbers, but I have no idea how. The lecturer promised that it would be quite easy. You can decompose other polinomials - (x^30-1, x^14 + x^7 + 1), I just want to understand how to do it. It is important that polynomial's degree should be high.

Comment: You should refer to cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: I thought about it, but i don't know how to use it here. I decomposed in wolfram x^14 + x^7 + 1 and result was composition of two cyclotomic, but I can't figure out that should be done (and why)

Comment: Use the recursive formula for $x^{28}-1$ in terms of cyclotomic polynomials -see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130162/factorising-xm-1-as-a-product-of-cyclotomic-polynomials). Then it is easy to see that $x^{14}+1=(x^2+1)(x^{12}- x^{10}+x^8 - \cdots +1$). So we have two irreducible factors.

Comment: Oh, i get it, thank you. But how should i do with x^14+x^7+1? I am trying to transform it to apply x^n+1 decomposition, but nothing works out. (this polynomial decompose into composition of 26th and 3rd cyclotomic polynomials)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_n$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Note that $i=\zeta_4$ is a root of $x^{14}+1$. Then all its roots are given by $i\zeta_{14}^k=i(-\zeta_7)^k$, $k=0,\dots,13$. The splitting field of $x^{14}+1$ is $\mathbb Q(i,\zeta_7)$. Then
$$x^{14}+1=\prod_{k=0}^{13}(x-i(-\zeta_7)^k)=\prod_{j=0}^6(x-i(-\zeta_7)^{2j})(x-i(-\zeta_7)^{2j+1})=\prod_{j=0}^6(x-i\zeta_7^{2j})(x+i\zeta_7^{2j+1}).$$
Note that $2j$ runs through $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ as $j$ takes values $0,\dots,6$, as well as $2j+1$. Therefore,
$$x^{14}+1=\prod_{j=0}^6(x-i\zeta_7^j)(x+i\zeta_7^j)=\prod_{j=0}^6(x^2+\zeta_7^{2j})=\prod_{j=0}^6(x^2+\zeta_7^j).$$
On the other hand,
$$\prod_{j=0}^6(x-\zeta_7^j)=x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1),$$
and then
$$\prod_{j=0}^6(-x+\zeta_7^j)=-(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$
Substituting $-x^2$ for $x$ leads to the result. For the irreducibility, note that $[\mathbb Q(i,\zeta_7):\mathbb Q]=12$, so the minimal polynomial of $i\zeta_7$ over $\mathbb Q$ has degree $12$.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to figure it out, we haven't studied splitting fields yet, so it's difficult for me.